# Url Rewrite management

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using URl Rewrite Management for redirect from

```
'http://example.com/magento/contacts' to 

'http://example.com/contact-us.html'
```

I entered "contacts" for ID Path and Target Path.and "contact-us.html" for the Request Path.
It will redirect me to

```
'http://example.com/magento/contact-us.html' instead of 'http://example.com/contact-us.html'.I need to redirect to     'http://example.com/contact-us.html'.
```

Kindly provide us the solution if have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rewrites are relative to the base url. If your base url is `example.com/magento` then you cannot use the url rewrites to get what you need.

Comment: Can I use absolute path? or any other solution.

Comment: maybe you should add this redirect from your .htaccess file.